# The position of "rather than"

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following two sentences grammatical? The first sentence read a bit strange to me, but English is not my first language, appreciate for view of a native speaker :)

> My main research insight is, rather than spending an enormous amount of time to get an optimal result, to develop algorithms that get suboptimal results at a significantly faster speed.

or

> Rather than spending an enormous amount of time to get an optimal result, my main research insight is to develop algorithms that get suboptimal results at a significantly faster speed.

Comment: Somehow it feels like your *rather-than*-clause is about your research insight rather than your algorithms. I'd recommend moving the *rather-than*-clause to somewhere after *develop algorithms*.

Answer (score 1):

They are both grammatically correct.  What you have here is an appositive clause, if I'm not mistaken on my terminology. Appositives by definition can be removed from a sentence, leaving it correct.

The only thing left is to decide where to place it just so your sentence is pleasing to hear or look at. I agree with Damkerng T. - you should put it at the end of your sentence.